# Solving cauchy riemann equations, finding all analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I need someone to check my work! I tried doing this as properly as possible, but I have no way to check whether this is correct.

Find $\textit{all}$ analytic functions $f = p(x,y) +iq(x,y) $ such that $p+q = xy$
(I'm using p's and q's since u's and v's look too similar. It gets messy quickly).

We have $$p_x + q_x = y \qquad p_y + q_y = x $$
$f$ is to be analytic so by Cauchy-Reimann we have $p_x = q_y$ and $p_y = -q_x$, thus we have:
$$y- q_x = x - p_y \qquad y+p_y = x- p_y$$
so 
$$ p_y = \frac{x-y}2$$

Thus $$p = \frac{xy}{2} - \frac{y^2}{4} + h(x)$$

Since $q = xy - p$ we have

$$ q = xy - \frac{xy}{2} + \frac{y^2}{4} - h(x) = \frac{xy}{2}+ \frac{y^2}{4} - h(x) $$

Again, since $p_x = q_y$ we have

$$\frac{y}2 + h'(x) = x - \frac{x}2 + \frac{y}2 = \frac{x}2 + \frac{y}2$$

so we have:

$$h(x) = \frac{x^2}4 + C $$

Putting it all together:

$$ f = p+iq = \frac{xy}{2} - \frac{y^2}{4} + \frac{x^2}4 + C + i\left( \frac{xy}{2}+ \frac{y^2}{4} - \frac{x^2}4 - C \right)$$

If we would like to rewrite this, we have:

$$f(z) = \frac{z^2}4 + C - i\left( \frac{z^2}4 + C \right) = (1-i)\left( \frac{z^2}4 + C \right)  $$

Now I would like to claim that for $C \in \mathbb{R}$, these are all solutions. Can I truly be sure of this? Did I make some mistake somewhere?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $p,q$ are real-valued. Then you can have it simpler by noting that $p(x,y) + q(x,y) = \operatorname{Im} \bigl((1+i)f(z)\bigr)$. But yes, these are all, you can be sure of that [but you can only be really sure if you know why you can be sure], and everything looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is of course possible that I overlooked a mistake, but since the result is correct, and I didn't see any error, I'm reasonably convinced that your work is correct.

Here, as in many situations, we can solve the task in an easier way if we apply a certain transformation to the problem. It is advisable to try to look for such simplifications. Not only does it save work when one spots them, it is also less likely to make mistakes in simpler situations.

With $f = p + iq$, note that $(1+i)f = (p-q) + i(p+q)$, so $xy$ is the imaginary part of $g = (1+i)f = u + iv$. Now the Cauchy-Riemann equations make it easy to find $u$, since

$$u_x = v_y = x \quad \text{and}\quad u_y = -v_x = -y,$$

so $u(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x^2 - y^2) + c$ for some $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Writing $g$ as a function of $z = x+iy$, we find

$$g(z) = \frac{z^2}{2} + c$$

for some (arbitrary) $c\in \mathbb{R}$. Since $(1-i)(1+i) = 2$, we then obtain

$$f(z) = \frac{1-i}{2} g(z) = \frac{1-i}{4} z^2 + \frac{1-i}{2}c,$$

with an arbitrary real $c$. (My $\frac{c}{2}$ corresponds to your $C$.)

Comment: How to you spot these shortcuts? I can follow the argument, but I would never ever be able to come up with this trick myself.

Comment: Experience. The unflattering truth is that I'm old, I have a lot of experience. If you see a couple of more such shortcuts taken by others, and remember to look for them yourself, you'll start seeing them soon. Of course, the more experience you have, the more shortcuts you know and the more opportunities you see. But it doesn't take a ton of experience to start seeing them.